# Boolean algebra, ABC'+AB'C'+A'BC' = (A+BC'+C)C', can anyone show it please

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was asked to prove the next formula - 
(A+BC'+C)C' = ABC'+AB'C'+A'BC'

i need to show all the stages of the simplification, i have all of the rules/identities.
i have tried many times and i did not make it, i always get something else 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

opening the brackets is done as with "regular" algebra, which yields:

```
AC' + BC'C' + CC'
```

from your identites:

```
C'C' = C'  
CC' = 0  
X + 0 = X
```

which imply that the above expression can be simplified to:

```
AC' + BC'
```

from here you should look to expand the expression by the following identities:

```
X*1 = X  
X + X' = 1
```

which yields:

```
AC'(B + B') + BC'(A + A')
```

expand the brackets as usual, change the order of multiplication with the identity XY = YX, cancel common terms based on X + X = X, and youre done...

someone should add a h/w tag to this question. i dont have any points...

Answer (score 0):

Show that both sides are `(A+B)C'`, using the fact that, for every `D` and `E`, `(D+D')E=E` (once in the RHS) and that `D+D'E=D+E` (once in the LHS and once in the RHS).